# Loading an external text file into vi

Tags: vi

Have got quite a large configuration file I want to load into Vi to play around with. When I cut and paste it into vi it only copies the first paragraph. Is there a way to copy the whole file?

Comment: How do you copy? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14225889/1945981

Comment: Do you use `:set paste`?

Comment: I just realized that you are using `vi`, not `vim`. Any reason for that?

Comment: Am just learning the code at the moment.

Comment: You should really be using `vim` instead.

Answer (score 5):

If what you want do is to copy the contents of another file into the file you are currently editing in Vi (which may be a new empty file) you may use the ex read command in Vi like so:

```
:r otherfile.conf
```

and it will be included after the line your cursor is currently on. To include it at the end of the file, you can insert a $ after the colon:

```
:$r otherfile.conf
```

To include it at the beginning of the file:

```
:0r otherfile.conf
```

To include it after line 123:

```
:123r otherfile.conf
```

Comment: cool positional modifiers in ex mode